# Minoccur is not working in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

In my scenario every time xsd will come dynamically, and i will have fixed XSD to validate against the XML,
when one keyword is missing in xml, its returning all mandatory and non mandatory keywords is missing

**XML** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice>
  <Invoice_Header>
    <lastname>str1234</lastname>
    <fathername>str1234</fathername>
    <mothername>str1234</mothername>
    <gender>str1234</gender>
    <age>123</age>
    <college>str1234</college>
    <city>str1234</city>
  </Invoice_Header>
</Invoice>
```

**XSD  :**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Invoice">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Invoice_Header">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="fisrtname" />
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lastname" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="fathername"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="mothername" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="gender"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:int" name="age"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="college" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="city" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**In above XML First name is missing,  but i am getting error like 
    one of all{firstnaem,lastname,fathername,mothername,gender,age,college,city} is expected**

Can any one help me to how to get only mandatory keywords is missing info only

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that a schema processor would allow customisation of error messages to the extent you are asking for. Different processors are going to produce different diagnostics. For what it's worth, this is Saxon's error message:

```
Validation error on line 3 column 21 of test.xml:
  In content of element <Invoice_Header>: element <fisrtname> is not present
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-model-group clause 3
```

Comment: Yes , i am using saxparserexception to capture the error messages